# Load XIB into ViewController Xamarin?

Tags: view, xamarin, xib, nib

It is possible to create and load view from a custom XIB in xamarin?
In Objective-C is like:

```
self.viewController = [[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController" bundle:nil];
self.window.rootViewController = self.viewController;
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

1 - Create your XIB file (example MyView).

2 - In the .cs related to the XIB file add this static creator method:

```cs
partial class MyView : UIView
    {
        public MyView (IntPtr handle) : base (handle)
        {    
        }

        public static MyView Create()
        {    
            var arr = NSBundle.MainBundle.LoadNib ("MyView", null, null);
            var v = arr.GetItem<MyView>(0);

            return v;
        }
    }
```

3 - Add `MyView` to the `ViewController`:

```cs
public partial class ViewController : UIViewController
{
    MyView v;
    public ViewController (IntPtr handle) : base (handle)
    {
    }

    public override void ViewDidLoad ()
    {
        base.ViewDidLoad ();

        v = MyView.Create();
        v.Frame = View.Frame;
        View.AddSubview (v);
    }
}
```

You can read more [here](https://developer.xamarin.com/recipes/ios/general/templates/using_the_ios_view_xib_template/).

Comment: static method Create is not a static constructor.

Comment: The idea here is to create the xib via a static method, not from a static constructor.

Comment: I know. You wrote that Create method is a static constructor. It isn't. It is a normal static method from C# perspective.

Comment: I get "Specified cast is not valid" exception here ` var v = Runtime.GetNSObject<SomeView> (arr.ValueAt(0)); `

Comment: Thats weird, can you create a github repo with that?

Comment: Thanks for clear explanation. `Runtime.GetNSObject` does not have definition anymore. `arr.GetItem<MyView>(0);` works instead. Please update the answer.