# Custom video page for xamarin ios

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I create some project that consists from videoplayer. For Xamarin android I implemented through messaging center.

On **android**:

**Page**(xamarin forms) **->** (**click** button and **sending message** to MainActivity) **->** calling  **MyVideoActivity** via intent

With android all works perfectly.

But I am newbie with ios and xamarin ios also.

And I don't know is this real to implement the same in **xamarin ios** through **messaging center** ?  Also I would like use **.xib** file(with ui, taken from Xcode). I am not sure how to implement it. I would like to do it through messaging center -> calling **custom ViewController** with my **.xib** file. **Is it real?**

p.s. I've found some example with **PageRenderer**, but don't investigate it. I am not sure that it will be suitable for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Call the following methods in your `MessagingCenter.Subscribe` lambda:

#### XIB-based ViewController:

```
var vc = new XIBBasedViewController();
// Set any public properties / call methods on your `XIBBasedViewController`
InvokeOnMainThread(() => UIApplication.SharedApplication.Windows[0].RootViewController.PresentViewController(vc, true, null));
```

#### Storyboard-based ViewController:

```
var storyboard = UIStoryboard.FromName("StoryBoardFileNameMinusExtension", null);
var vc = storyboard.InstantiateViewController("AStoryBoardIDAssignedToYourViewController") as AViewControllerSubClass;
// Set any public properties / call methods on your `AViewControllerSubClass`
InvokeOnMainThread(() => UIApplication.SharedApplication.Windows[0].RootViewController.PresentViewController(vc, true, null));
```

**Note**: A good place to setup your messaging center subscribes is in the `FinishedLaunching` of the `AppDelegate` class.

Comment: Thanks for help, but I cann't to show UI in ViewConroller with .xib file. I use this exmaple  https://stackoverflow.com/a/37762881/3521689 , but getting exception in AppDelegate.cs  
  (System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> Foundation.MonoTouchException: Objective-C exception thrown.  Name: NSUnknownKeyException Reason: [<NSObject 0x6000006170c0> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key onStopOutlet.)

Comment: @IgorLevkivskiy `key onStopOutlet`... Are you using a pre-existing xib from an Xcode project? If so you have not created the matching outlets in your code.

Comment: Yeah you are right, I forgot about adding outlet in code. Thanks for great helping, everything works fine:-)

Comment: @IgorLevkivskiy Glad to hear that you got it working 