# Adding new view controller doesn't create XIB file

Tags: xamarin, visual-studio-2019, mvvmcross

I'm following mvvmcross [tutorial](https://www.mvvmcross.com/documentation/tutorials/tipcalc/a-xamarinios-ui-project?scroll=1670), where it says:

1. Create an initial UIViewController
2. Create a folder called Views.
3. Within this, add a new ‘View Controller’ and call it TipView.

This will generate three classes:

1. TipView.cs
2. TipView.designer.cs
3. TipView.xib

When I add new UIViewController
[image: When I add UIViewController]

it adds two following classes with no xib file.

```
namespace TipCalc.iOS.Views
{
    [Register("UniversalView")]
    public class UniversalView : UIView
    {
        public UniversalView()
        {
            Initialize();
        }

        public UniversalView(RectangleF bounds) : base(bounds)
        {
            Initialize();
        }

        void Initialize()
        {
            BackgroundColor = UIColor.Red;
        }
    }

    [Register("UIViewController1")]
    public class UIViewController1 : UIViewController
    {
        public UIViewController1()
        {
        }

        public override void DidReceiveMemoryWarning()
        {
            // Releases the view if it doesn't have a superview.
            base.DidReceiveMemoryWarning();

            // Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
        }

        public override void ViewDidLoad()
        {
            View = new UniversalView();

            base.ViewDidLoad();

            // Perform any additional setup after loading the view
        }
    }
}
```

What is the correct way to add xib file a link it with view controller?

Comment: Hi, have a look at this discussion: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37762812/load-xib-into-viewcontroller-xamarin. It should also will work for iOS mvvmcross project.